# Изменение фона через HEX калибровку

Tags: javascript

Идея: заполнить массив числами и буквами, чтобы создать HEX-калибровку для фона. 
Проблема: при заполнении буквами цикл почему-то присваивает самую последнюю букву f. Не могу понять, почему самую последнюю, а не в случайном порядке.

```js
let body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
let arr = []; 
arr.length = 6;

for (let i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2); // выпадает 0 или 1
  let letters = ['a','b','c','d','e','f'];
  if(random === 0) { // если 0, то итерация заполняется числом от 0 до 9
    arr[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
  }
  if(random === 1) { // если 1, то итерация заполняется буквой из массива letters
    for(j=0; j < letters.length;j++) { // НАСКОЛЬКО Я ПОНИМАЮ, ТО ПРОБЛЕМА ИМЕННО В ЭТОМ ЦИКЛЕ
      arr[i] = letters[j];
    }
  }
}
arr = arr.join('');
body.style.backgroundColor = '#' + arr;
```

Comment: Что такое HEX-калибровка?

Comment: Получение каждого из 6 значений HEX цвета в формате "#123456". Далее я сделал функцию, которая за единицу времени изменяет цвет (=откалибровывает заново) фона.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш цикл с j просто перебирает все буквы и по очереди присваиват для arr[i] каждую букву, в итоге присваивается последняя буква(выполняется последняя итерация для последнего элемента letters, она и перезаписывает), надо просто брать случайный элемент массива.

```js
let body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
let arr = []; 
arr.length = 6;

for (let i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2); // выпадает 0 или 1
  let letters = ['a','b','c','d','e','f'];
  if(random === 0) { // если 0, то итерация заполняется числом от 0 до 9
    arr[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
  }
  if(random === 1) { // если 1, то итерация заполняется буквой из массива letters
      arr[i] = letters[Math.floor(Math.random()*letters.length)];
  }
}
arr = '#' + arr.join('');
body.style.backgroundColor = arr;

console.log(arr)
```

Более короткая версия:

```js
let body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]
    letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
    rand = n => Math.floor(Math.random() * n)
    arr = letters.map(() => {
      if (Math.random() < 0.5)
        return rand(10)

      return letters[rand(letters.length)]
    })

arr = '#' + arr.join('')
body.style.backgroundColor = arr

console.log(arr)
```

Как вариант можно брать случайный символ из строки.

```js
function getRandomColor () {
  const letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'
  let color = '#'
  for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)]
  }
  return color
}

console.log(getRandomColor())
```

Короче этого варианта на js вряд ли существует:

```js
const get = () => '#'+((1<<24)*Math.random()|0).toString(16)

console.log(get(), get(), get())
```

Answer (score 1):

Причина в том, что вы в первом случае( с числами) использовали рандом, а с буквами забыли. Вместо этого использовали цикл, который перебирает массив с буквами и перезаписывает массив. В результате получаете последний элемент массива (в Вашем случае это буква "f"). Также я немного оптимизировал Ваш вариант, пользуйтесь.

```
function rand(num){
   return Math.floor(Math.random() * num);
}

let body = document.body,
    arr = new Array(6),
    letters = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']; 


for (let i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  arr[i] = !rand(2) ? rand(10) : letters[rand(letters.length)];
}

arr = arr.join('');
body.style.backgroundColor = '#' + arr;
```